# Can't find Word doc I was working on within Outlook, but it was opened as an “eml” file after download from Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I was looking at an email in Gmail and wanted to open it up separately. I ended up clicking download, which downloaded an `eml` file and when I clicked on it, it opened in Outlook.

I opened the Word doc attached *within* the email and worked on it, while clicking save every 15 minutes or so.

Once I finished, I closed the doc after saving one last time, and then closed the email. However, the document is nowhere to be found on my computer.

Any chance at all that it is retrievable or did I just learn a lesson?

Comment: Open `C:\Users\rYour_User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook`, and check if the file is in one of the folder.

Comment: Thanks but no INetCache folder exists...A Caches folder exists, but nothing in there either.

Comment: Did you try searching by enabling show all hidden files and folders also?

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned above, you could find the location of your Outlook attachment cache via HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Security\OutlookSecureTempFolder.

Please check the "Hide items" option in windows view to show hidden items and check the cache location. If you still could not find your file, I'm afraid this might be unrecoverable.